# Delay wow js animation until page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wow.js

I'm using `wow js` on my website and I need a way to delay animation until page fully loaded. Not `data-wow-delay`. I'm also using `preloader` so when page loaded animations already happened.

This is my first question. If you guys can help me I really appreciate It.

Comment: You can use page ready jQuery function.  https://api.jquery.com/ready . You must google it first then post question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the page to be ready you can use `ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Trigger animation
});
```

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/ready

If you want all the resources(images) to be loaded, use `load` event of `window`:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Trigger animation
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I used .on load function and it's working now. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
<body onload="script();">
```

or

```
document.onload = function ...
```

Comment: Because the OP has a `jQuery` tag, I'd point them towards jQuery's `ready` method.  `addEventListener` is a better fallback than `document.onload` since that property can be overwritten by another script.